# Django view not redirecting based on response

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I would like this Django view to redirect according to server response but it still stays on `'callback.html'` no matter the response, any insight on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
def callback(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        response = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        print (response)

        result_code = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]

        if result_code == 0:
            amount = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][0]["Value"]
            mpesa_receipt_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][1]["Value"]
            transaction_date = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][2]["Value"]
            phone_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][3]["Value"]

            str_transaction_date = str(transaction_date)
            transaction_datetime = datetime.strptime(
                str_transaction_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            aware_transaction_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(
                transaction_datetime)
            
            our_model = Mpesa.objects.create(
                MpesaReceiptNumber=mpesa_receipt_number,
                PhoneNumber=phone_number,
                Amount=amount,
                TransactionDate=aware_transaction_datetime,
            )
            our_model.save()

            return redirect('realtor:create')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:contact'))

    return render(request, 'callback.html')
```

Comment: Are you even making a POST request? You are redirecting only if the request is a POST request.

Comment: Is there another way around it?